# How to configure CircleCI IaC (Terraform) pipeline to use multiple repositories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, circleci

I am trying to run `Terraform` code through a `CircleCI` `IaC` pipeline to provision an S3 bucket in `AWS`.

- I have Terraform code to provision S3 bucket `s3.tf` inside a repo named `terraform`
- I have runtime variables in an `s3.tfvars` file in a repo named `tfvars`

So I would like to do these steps in my IaC pipeline:

1. Clone `terraform` repo
2. Clone `tfvars` repo
3. Run `terraform init`
4. Run `terraform plan`
5. Run `terraform apply`

I have a config.yaml that looks like this below. I am not sure how to clone 2 repos in CircleCI pipeline (`terraform` and `tfvars`). Any pointers on how to do this?

```
version: '2.1'
parameters:
  ENV:
    type: string
    default: ""
orbs:
  terraform: 'circleci/terraform@2.1'
workflows:
  deploy_infrastructure:
     jobs:
     - terraform/init:
          path: .
     -  terraform/validate:
          path: .
          checkout: true
          context: terraform
     -  terraform/plan:
           path: .
           checkout: true
           context: terraform
           persist-workspace: true
           requires:
            - terraform/validate
           workspace: parameters.ENV
     - terraform/apply:
          attach-workspace: true
          context: terraform
          filters:
            branches:
              only: 'circleci-project-setup'
          requires:
            - terraform/plan
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue:

`````
version: '2.1'
orbs:
  terraform: 'circleci/terraform@2.1'
jobs:
  single-job-lifecycle:
    executor: terraform/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          command: >-
                GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -vv -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
                git clone https://<url>/Tfvars.git
          name: GIT Clone TFvars repository
      - terraform/init:
          path: .
      - terraform/validate:
          path: .
      - run:
          name: "terraform plan"
          command: terraform plan -var-file "./Tfvars/tfvars/dev/s3.tfvars"
      - run:
          name: "terraform apply"
          command: terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file "./Tfvars/tfvars/dev/s3.tfvars"
    working_directory: ~/src
workflows:
  single-job-lifecycle:
    jobs:
      - single-job-lifecycle````
`````